# Scan files on network storage with android MediaScannerConnection.scanFile

Tags: android, ftp-client

In Android SDK the fonction "scanFile" from "MediaScannerConnection" class allows to add files in the MediaStore, and then to use nice android apps to display and play multimedia files.

The "ScanFile" method need a "path" parameter (the path to the file to be scanned).

Is there a way to build a content provider for files on a ftp server and use the "scanFile" method to add them to the media store ?

What would be the "path" for these files on a network storage unit ?

Answer (score 0):

You could see MediaScanner.java and MediaScannerConnection.java files. Currently it picks the mount path like /mnt/sdcard and then scanFile function is called on that. Also, in init.rc, you mention about the mount points. Probably, it may give you some indicators in that direction.

Vibgyor

Comment: To mount a network drive using the ftp protocol, I need a special kernel on Android. Shouldn't I ?